# Filter like % for a list - Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

The is a list filter_value= [a, b, c]
session.query.filter(mytable.column.in_(filter_value)).all()

For this case the filter will return exactly the value equal to each item in the list (filter_value).

However, I want filter like in SQL such as select *from mytable where column like a%, b%, c%, ...%
I mean "Like each element in the list". Sorry if I explain not good
What would i do for it? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean SQL `LIKE`, I think this works with id being a string.

```py
session.query(MyUserClass).filter(or_(*[MyUserClass.id.like(prefix + '%') for prefix in filter_list]))
```

Comment: Thank you very much Wilson, really appreciate your answer. May I ask more a bit about '*', what doest it mean?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: Converts arg list into arguments for function that takes dynamic number of arguments like or_(*args).